# ASP.NET GridView Not Appearing After Button Click

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, .net, gridview

I have a dropdown list named `ddlSvcEngr` getting values from data source. I want the gridview show the results from the database based on the selection from `ddlSvcEngr`. But every time I click the view button there's no gridview appearing. Here's the code:

HTML:

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddlSvcEngr" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" DataTextField="rep_svcengr" DataValueField="rep_svcengr" CssClass="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" Width="300px" AppendDataBoundItems="true">    
<asp:Button ID="btnView" runat="server" Text="View" CssClass="btn btn-primary" Width="300px" OnClick="btnView_Click" />
<asp:GridView ID="gvResults" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" ShowFooter="True">
            <Columns>
                <asp:BoundField ItemStyle-Width="150px" DataField="rep_svcengr" HeaderText="Service Engineer" >
                    <ItemStyle Width="150px"></ItemStyle>
            </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:jasonsvcConnectionString %>" SelectCommand="SELECT [rep_svcengr], [rep_company], [rep_vessel], [rep_wo], [rep_brand], [rep_model], [rep_eqpt], [rep_sn] FROM [reports]"></asp:SqlDataSource>
```

Code Behind:

```
private void bgSvcEngr()
    {
        string conString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["jasonsvcConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
        string query = "SELECT rep_svcengr,rep_company,rep_vessel,rep_wo,rep_brand,rep_model,rep_eqpt,rep_sn FROM reports WHERE rep_svcengr='@svcengr'";
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@svcengr", ddlSvcEngr.SelectedItem.Value);
        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(conString))
        {
            using (SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter())
            {
                cmd.Connection = con;
                sda.SelectCommand = cmd;
                using (DataSet ds = new DataSet())
                {
                    sda.Fill(ds);
                    gvResults.DataSource = ds;
                    gvResults.DataBind();
                }
            }
        }
    }

protected void btnView_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {            
            bgSvcEngr();
    }
```

Note: Everytime I remove the line `WHERE rep_svcengr='" + ddlSvcEngr.SelectedIndex.ToString() + "'` from the command query. The gridview appears after View button clicked.

I don't have any idea what would be the problem why the gridview does not appear every time I put the WHERE command to the query.

Comment: `AddWithValue()` can be problematic.  It is better to add parameters with an explicit type.

Comment: You checked running query in database? you get records ?

Comment: @MuhammadSaqlain yes. I did check the records from same query. It shows the table.

@GordonLinoff even not using `AddWithValue()` no gridview appears. 

From my note, all data from the table `reports` show once I removed the `where` syntax from the query.

Comment: put a breakpoint at this point and see what Index you get **ddlSvcEngr.SelectedIndex.ToString()**. I believe you get a ID which is not present id database and you get zero records from database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Get rid of the single quotes:

Replace:

```
WHERE rep_svcengr='@svcengr'
```

With:

```
WHERE rep_svcengr=@svcengr
```

[image]

```
public partial class WebForm1 : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SelectByColor();
    }
    private void SelectByColor()
    {
        string conString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["AdventureWorks2014ConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
        string query = "SELECT productid, name, color FROM production.product WHERE color=@pcolor";
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pcolor", DropDownList1.SelectedItem.Value);
        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(conString))
        {
            using (SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter())
            {
                cmd.Connection = con;
                sda.SelectCommand = cmd;
                using (DataSet ds = new DataSet())
                {
                    sda.Fill(ds);
                    GridView1.DataSource = ds;
                    GridView1.DataBind();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```